# How can I center Twitter-Bootstrap 3 navbar links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, centering, navbar

How can I center the buttons in the jsFiddle I set up so that the buttons are equally spaced and centered within and through-out the navbar?

http://jsfiddle.net/3GQyq/3/

I have tried different methods such as

```
display:inline-block;margin:0 auto; text-align:center;
```

But I cannot get it to work.

If you could  give a little explanation instead of just fixing the CSS as I want to learn so I do not have to keep coming back here.

EDIT:

[image: http://img1.123freevectors.com/wp-content/uploads/icon_big/038_icon_beautiful-navigation-bar-free-vector.jpg]
Just like how they are centered here ^.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3** has a `nav-justified` class that can be used on `nav`. No extra CSS required:

```
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-justified">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/72519

---

Based on the comments, to have full-width centered links using the **`navbar-nav`** class, use flexbox...

```
.navbar-center {
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
}
.navbar-center>li {
    flex:1 1 auto;
}

<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center text-center">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/6ZE3obnpuP

---

**Also see**
[Bootstrap NavBar with left, center or right aligned items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733447/bootstrap-navbar-with-left-center-and-right-aligned-items/20362024#20362024)
[Center Navbar in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39945599/center-navbar-in-bootstrap/42736011#42736011)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, however if you take alook at this fiddle I am having conflicting issue. Do you you have any suggestions?
http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6582/

Comment: Same here, with class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified" the manu shrink to the left, any workaround for this?

Comment: remove the navbar-nav class.

Comment: `nav-justified` is for pills and tabs, not the navbar. **Warning: Using this class on a navbar breaks the navbar styles.**

Comment: I updated the answer specifically for **`navbar-nav`**.

Answer (score 3):

Add the style

```
.nav{
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will center the text in li.

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3GQyq/5/)**

These styles should be sufficient. You were trying to apply styles to to the wrong element.

```
// This is being applied by the bootstrap
// Set it to 25px instead of the default 15px
.navbar{
    padding : 0 25px;
}

// Gave a width of 110px for each li
// as the container is following a fixed width format
li{
    width:110px;
}
```

Comment: pleas re-check my questions I have edited it. You are missing my point, not the text but the buttons themselves.

Comment: But I don't see those buttons in the fiddle

Comment: @sushhanth

Please re-check my fiddle, I have updated things to make it a little more clearer. Prehaphs I was describing things incorrectly. I mean the links in the navbar.

Comment: So you want them to be placed horizontally instead of the current vertical alignement

Comment: As you can see, all the buttons are aligned to the left, as if there is a
`.float:left;`
style applied to it. I want the buttons to be centered in the nav bar that will stretch out the full width of navbar. Look at the image I posted on the question. See how them nav buttons are centered the full width of the navbar, where as mine are all pulled over to the left?

Comment: There is a `float:left` property applied to the li elements that is coming from the `bootstrap.css` file

Comment: setting the width explicitly helped