# How to justify navbar-nav in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm attempting to justify a [`navbar`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) (make the navbar contents stretch) in Bootstrap 3. I've added `margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1000px;` to the `nav*` classes, and also attempted to add a `container` element as a parent to the `ul`. As a last check, I did what was suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18102118/1383785) by adding `navbar-justified` to the `navbar` class, but this caused everything to scrunch together on the left without justifying the entire navbar.

Doing a `nav nav-justified` `ul` does make the `ul` center, but it doesn't retain the styles of the `navbar-nav` class since it's not part of the `ul`, and it doesn't look great when the screen is smaller than 768px.

How do I justify a Bootstrap 3 `navbar`?

Edit: For those who are interested in a more complete answer, here is some code I use in production:

```
// Stylesheet
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}

// Navbar
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="group.html">Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="positions.html">Positions</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And [here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KLMuk/1/). You may have to stretch the size of the `result` box for it to show correctly. If you're interested in centering the actual list without the nav stretching to full width, see [David Taiaroa's jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2fntE/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turns out that there is a `float: left` property by default on all `navbar-nav>li` elements, which is why they were all scrunching up to the left. Once I added the code below, it made the `navbar` both centered and not scrunched up.

```
.navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else who's looking to center a `navbar`.

Comment: This stops the nav li elements being inline with bootstrap 3 - David's answer works better.

Comment: Where does this cause an issue? Both answers are good, in my opinion (although I'm biased because I wrote one) but they attempt to do different things... Look at my and David's jsfiddles.

Comment: Okay I may have used your code incorrectly looking at your sample, however your question is about centring a nav bar rather than making it justified (quite different) and I would say David's answer is closer to that.

Answer (score 66):

You can justify the navbar contents by using:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .navbar-nav{
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: table;
     table-layout: fixed;
     float: none;
  }
}
```

See this live: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/2fntE/

Comment: Would this work across multiple browsers? Unfortunately I might have to support IE 7

Comment: @David thanks, did you try it with .navbar-right?
It seems like once you also have another .navbar-right your solution is pushing the .navbar-right downward.

Comment: @GuyKorland, I haven't tried it with a navbar-right, though what you mention doesn't surprise me. Another approach might be more suitable in that case. If you want to start a jsFiddle I would be happy to play around with it for you ;)

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa, thanks for the offer :) in fact the solution was pretty simple, only switch the order between the different parts of the navbar, see http://jsfiddle.net/gkorland/AMeYh/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/gkorland/AMeYh/2/

Comment: Good going @GuyKorland, switching the order isn't something I would have thought of quickly ;)

Comment: If using `{less}` instead of pure CSS, I'd suggest using the `@screen-sm-min` variable instead of the hardcoded `768px`.

Comment: Hi @DavidTaiaroa

Your code works well, but if I want to put search form on the same line, the form will put on the new line.

Comment: @TheHung , do you want the search form centered along with your other menu links?

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa I mean that logo on the left side, menu in the center and search form on the right side. If you set `float: none`, search form will put on the new line.

Comment: @TheHung, one possibility if you have space would be something like http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/q3940bs5/  I'm sure there would be a cleaner flexbox option as well. Good luck ;)

Comment: Instead of justifying this, how can we center the navbar?

Answer (score 37):

To justify the bootstrap 3 navbar-nav justify menu to 100% width you can use this code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: auto;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        display: table-cell;
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It not only centers everything, but also justifies.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more easy solution. just remove the "navbar-nav" class and add "nav-justified".

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

and for the css

```
@media ( min-width: 768px ) { 
    .navbar > .container {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .navbar-header,.navbar-brand,.navbar .navbar-nav,.navbar .navbar-nav > li {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .collapse.navbar-collapse {
        width: auto;
        clear: none;
    }
}
```

see it live http://www.bootply.com/103172

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I would like share my solution. I spent several hours trying to make a justified navigation menu. You do not really need to modify anything in bootstrap css. Just need to add the correct class in the html.

```
   <nav class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">Brand Name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsable-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified">
                <li><a href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This CSS code will simply remove the navbar-brand class when the screen reaches 768px.

```
media@(min-width: 768px){
   .navbar-brand{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use this below code for working justified nav

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```