# Bootstrap nav-justified stacks li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I was wondering what does cause the li elements to stack on each other when I use nav-justified.

I ve read there is an issue with IE older versions, but I'm testing it on a new version Chrome.

```
<div id="header" class="row">
  <div id="backgroundImage" class="pagebg"></div>
  <div id="nav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">                     
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">toggle Navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-justified">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my first actual Bootstrap Website and I know there is still lot to learn.
There was nothing about the issue in Bootstrap Doc.

Could something being overriding it?

I 've read that there is a bug in safari browsers while using nav-justified.
Is it a bad idea to use nav-justified? Should I use css to manipulate the text?
Or is there a simple explanation on why is bugging and stacking everything together?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [**Justified**](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-justified)

> Easily make **tabs** or **pills** equal widths of their parent at screens
>   wider than 768px with .nav-justified. On smaller screens, the nav
>   links are stacked.

Without further CSS tuning, the `nav-justified` only works for `nav-pills` and `nav-tabs`, try changing `navbar-nav` to tabs or pills.

see http://jsfiddle.net/x3yz13c5/5/

If you insist using `navbar-nav` try something like

```
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
}
```

Similar thread can be seen here [How to justify navbar-nav in Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073813/how-to-justify-navbar-nav-in-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `navbar-nav` class from the `<ul>` element inside

```
<div id="collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">...</div>
```

If it's set, following CSS rule is applied to your `<li>` element:

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
    .navbar-nav > li {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

The `float: left` causes that "stack" effect.

Comment: If this is indeed the solution, OP should just open a browser inspector and spend five seconds himself to check for this, as it is very easy to spot which styles are applied to each element.