# Justifying Bootstrap navbar-nav list items with even space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar menu with a few list items. I need even white space between them, and this is difficult for me since some list items are longer than others. 
[image]

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073813/how-to-justify-navbar-nav-in-bootstrap-3) but it doesn't address my problem, though I did use it for centering and justifying the navbar.

Here is a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/UjY99PYpe7

Comment: Is a fixed padding for each list item what you are looking for, like so: http://www.bootply.com/De8KGK6Gz4 ??

Comment: @LuukSkeur No. Your solution isn't responsive. And goes on two lines at some point.

Comment: Why on earth was this downvoted?!

Comment: @RachelS some hater, I'll vote up to level the field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this css in your bootply:

```
.navbar-nav {
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: Genius solution :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Is not my idea, I saw long ago in a blog and I used several times

Comment: @RachelS I thought you wanted no blankspaces between buttons.

Comment: @warkentien2 I do need space, it just has to be even space between them. I'll look at your full width idea tomorrow.

Comment: @RachelS do test! it looks closer to your initial bootply layout, but even spaced.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish your buttons to be **full width**

### Try this `flexbox` solution

```css
.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%; 
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Works, too, but already implemented pp's suggestion so will stay with that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RachelS just giving more problems for future users. thanks!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I used your solution today on a different site ;)

Comment: Thanks for telling me! I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Flexbox subdivided the space evenly among elements. `flex-grow` stretches element to fill in the entire space created for it. You can apply different `flex-grow` sizes to give that element a proportionally larger space.