# How to center Buttons within a Bootstrap 3 navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, centering

Trying to center buttons within a bootstrap 3 navbar. I've found some examples here, but they didn't seem to apply to (or work with) buttons.

Here's my example...
http://jsfiddle.net/jayinthebay/e3hj0kzw/

I'm just trying to center BUTTON1, BUTTON2, BUTTON3 on the nav.

I've tried:

```
text-align: center;
```

But I guess that's not it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I center Twitter-Bootstrap 3 navbar buttons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093630/how-can-i-center-twitter-bootstrap-3-navbar-buttons)

Comment: @myninjaname as mentioned I found other examples on stack (including the one you referenced). The solution there was to use "nav-justified" which did not work in my tests with buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Just changing the `navbar-header` to

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="text-align: center">
```

worked for me. Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e3hj0kzw/1/).

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navbar {
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: @StardustGogeta When editing a code-only answer for formatting (which is helpful) do not add anything. It is the answerers job to provide an explanation. Adding somethign which looks at first glance like an explanation is not helpful, especially not the "Try this:" which makes the initially assertive answer look like a weak "I am not sure about this...". If you need to add some non-code to avoid the system complaining, then please find a different post to improve instead.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `navbar-header` with `text-center`

Like this:

```
<div class="text-center" >  //instead of navbar-header i used text-center


            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">BUTTON1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">BUTTON2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">BUTTON3</button>


            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
```

Here is the [**Demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3hj0kzw/3/)